# contains in MySQL without LIKE

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

- table 1 - Val 1(example: `TOP`)
- table 2 - Val 2(example: `TOP,TOP_12,TOP_14` [Note : this is a String])

Java has `Contains` method to check the value of `Val 1` is in `Val 2`, I want to know how to write a query to know `Val 1` is in `Val 2` or not. I don't want to use `LIKE` since the `Val 2` (string) contains all the values with `TOP` so the count with `LIKE` query will be 3.

Comment: You want to know if val 1 it's in val2 or you want to know how many times?

Comment: Please update your question and show sample data along with the tabular output you expect.  Java and SQL are very different tools.

Comment: @divyaDivi try my solution

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer thanks for ur link. it is very helpful for me. Since its my first question in Stackoverflow, i didnt have any idea how to propose a question. I apologise for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in a few ways.

DEMO db schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `val1` varchar(128) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `t1` (`val1`) VALUES('TOP_1'),('TOP_12'),('TOP_13');

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `val2` varchar(128) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `t2` (`val2`) VALUES('TOP_1,TOP_3'),('TOP_4,TOP_12');
```

[FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) demo:

```
SELECT t1.*, IF(t2.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS in_val2
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.val1, t2.val2)
```

[DEMO (in SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecc2ac/1)

[INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) demo:

```
SELECT t1.*, IF(t2.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS in_val2
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON INSTR(CONCAT('|', REPLACE(t2.val2, ',', '|'), '|'), CONCAT('|', t1.val1, '|'))
```

[INSTR DEMO (in SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecc2ac/7)

Comment: Hello Neodan, FIND_IN_SET can be used in "MySQL Version: 5.6" but am using "Oracle SQL Developer-3.1.05" am sorry i forgot to mention it in my earlier comment

Comment: @divyaDivi Unfortunately I don't have a possibility try to write a SQL on `Oracle SQL Developer`. I added a solution with `INSTR` to my answer (Oracle also have `INSTR`). Maybe it will help to you.

Comment: @divyaDivi How is going? Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `LOCATE(substr,str)` for this.

For more reference please refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

Comment: It is a bad idea to use `LOCATE ` in this case because e.g. `TOP_1` will be found in `TOP_12` (-;